# Only execute function if mouse has hovered for more than 1 second

Tags: jquery

I would like to add and remove classes on elements when a user hovers over an element, but only if their cursor has been on it for more than 1 second for example. How can I achieve this?

```
$("#thumbs div").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#thumbs div').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

Comment: There's a hoverintent plugin out there that serves this purpose.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a timer:

```
var timer;
$("#thumbs div").mouseenter(function() {
    var that = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#thumbs div').removeClass('hovered');
        $(that).addClass('hovered');
    }, 1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGRcH/

Answer (score 2):

You could use hover and delay:

```
$("#thumbs div").hover(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovered').siblings().removeClass('hovered');
    });
},function() {
    $(this).finish();
});
```

Comment: This displays 1 second after any amount of hovering - @bfavaretto's answer is for a full second of hovering.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bSuuy/2/

```
var timer;

$("button").on("mouseenter", function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".box").css("background", "blue");
    }, 1000);
});

$("button").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".box").css("background", "red");
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```